# turning an image to pdf and print it to the printer without the print dialogue in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, pdf, printing, jpeg

I am developing a photo booth system and I would like to print the photo automatically after clicking a button on my web page without any print dialogue and I have to convert it into pdf to use the silent print function. I would like to ask if anyone could give me some sample codes for php or javascript for converting the format and print the converted file automatically to the printer.
Thanks in advance

Comment: php and js sound like terrible languages for this

Answer (score 1):

If you're pulling up a remote site through a browser, you can't bypass the printer selection and have it just print.  That would be a security issue (imagine a malicious site just sending thousands of print jobs to an unsuspecting user's printer).

Since you said this is for a photo booth, it sounds like you'll have control of the browser that this runs on, which means you can install [this plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/seamless-print/) (meant for kiosk systems) for Firefox that would let you bypass the print dialog and just print whatever job is to be printed.

If the PHP code that you're running is on the same computer as the browser (and the browser is accessing it through, say, `http://localhost`), then you could using PHP to send the job to the locally-connected printer by invoking CUPS.

Comment: thanks nick, is there any plug-ins for google chrome?

Comment: It appears as though there's a configuration option for Chrome without the need for a plugin:
https://mycartpos.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/200868343-Enable-kiosk-printing-print-automatically-for-Google-Chrome-on-Windows